# How to decompress this encoded javascript code?

Tags: javascript, html

Is there a tool to decode and decompress code that looks like this?

```js
<script type='text/javascript'>
var pageresults=tyOptions.postperPage;var numshowpage=8;var upPageWord=&#39;&lt;i class=&quot;fa fa-angle-double-left&quot;&gt;&lt;/i&gt;&#39;;var downPageWord=&#39;&lt;i class=&quot;fa fa-angle-double-right&quot;&gt;&lt;/i&gt;&#39;;var urlactivepage=location.href;var home_page=&quot;/&quot;;
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go. Unescape the HTML escaping and pretty print

```
var numshowpage = 8;
var upPageWord = '<i class="fa fa-angle-double-left"></i>';
var downPageWord = '<i class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></i>';
var urlactivepage = location.href;
var home_page = "/";
```

Comment: How to unescape?

Comment: Oh there are many online tools, just google HTML unescaper and try any of the tools available